# Не доверять File.Exists() и использовать try/catch?

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, файловая-система, try-catch

На одной из страниц форума https://stackoverflow.com/a/6186400/2948684, где идет обсуждение `if/else vs. try/catch` автор ответа все же рекомендует код, который изменяет состояние приложения с помощью внешних источников, обвертывать в блок `try/catch` и приводя код

```
if(File.Exists("file.txt"))
    File.Delete("file.txt")
```

говорит, что даже если выражение `File.Exists("file.txt")` вернет true, то перед тем как стек успеет перейти к `File.Delete("file.txt")`, что-то может изменить файл извне.

Я удивился, неужели метод `File.Exists()` выполняется так медленно. Да я также читал на других страницах, что в случае с `File.Exists()` `try/catch` быстрее .

И тем не менее, в эти миллисекунды разве может что-то произойти. Да и эти миллисекунды решил подсчитать. К примеру, что на SSD, что на HDD проверка существования файла в корне диска заняла у метода `File.Exists()` в среднем **12 миллисекунд**. Конечно, если сервер будет обращаться по локалке к отдельному файловому серверу это займет чуть больше, но ведь чуть.

---

### Вопрос

Ну а вопрос мой будет звучать так: если я правильно понял автора, то какой сценарий на практике предполагает возможность такой ситуации? Быть может что-то такое может произойти:

1. `Процесс A` начал переименовывать файла и завис;
2. `Процесс Б` выполнил `File.Exists()` и вернул true;
3. `Процесс A` ожил и переименовал файл;
4. `Процесс Б` выполняет `File.Delete()` и вернул исключение.

Comment: Вопрос с C# в общем-то не связан, описанная проблема актуальна в любом языке в любой ОС

Comment: на самом деле в случае с File.Delete нет смысла проверять File.Exists так как [_If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown._](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy пусть будет тогда Open. Суть вопроса не меняется.

Comment: Если "процесс завис" заменить на "у процесса кончилось выделенное время", то ситуация вполне обыденная. Но что делать, если файл появился, когда `File.Exists()` уже решил, что файла нет?

Comment: @Lyth но я тогда не представляю эту нагрузку, которая каждые 12 миллисекунд вносит изменения на диск. Если бы речь шла об ОЗУ тогда ещё понятно.

Comment: `Быть может что-то такое может произойти:` - вполне, более того, Exists не проверяет заблокирован ли файл (например, открыт для записи другим приложением), т.е. файл существует, но его не удалить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, именно так.

Об этом пишет Эрик Липперт в одной из лучших своих статей [Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/):

Я приведу фрагмент в собственном переводе, а вы обязательно прочтите оригинал.

> И наконец, **исключения внешнего мира** немного похожи на **досадные** исключения с той разницей, что они не являются результатом ошибок в дизайне. Скорее, они отражают вторжение грубой, неизящной реальности в замечательную, кристально чистую логику вашей программы. Посмотрите на этот C#-псевдокод:
>
> ```
> try
> {
>   using ( File f = OpenFile(filename, ForReading) )
>   {
>     // что-то делаем
>   }
> }
> catch (FileNotFoundException)
> {
>   // обработать ненайденный файл
> }
> ```
>
> Можно ли избавиться от блока try/catch?
>
> ```
> if (!FileExists(filename))
>   // обработать ненайденный файл
> else
>   using ( File f = ...
> ```
>
> Это уже не та же самая программа. Теперь в ней есть «race condition». Какой-то другой процесс мог удалить, залочить, переместить файл, или поменять права доступа между `FileExists` и `OpenFile`.
>
> Может быть, мы просто недостаточно хитры? Может, можно как-то заблокировать файл? Нет, это не поможет. Носитель может быть удалён пользователем из дисковода, сеть может упасть…
>
> Вы обязаны ловить исключения внешнего мира, потому что они всегда могут произойти, как бы вы не старались их избежать: это события внешнего мира, у вас нет над ними контроля.

---

Конкретно отвечая на ваш вопрос: проверка существования может быть и быстрой, но удаление файла могло начаться и *до* начала этой проверки. И закончиться как раз к её концу.